# Как заблокировать использование кнопки,после использования?Java

Tags: java, android

Как заблокировать использование кнопки,после использования?

Comment: А как вы думаете? Что у вас уже получилось?

Comment: Что такое "использование кнопки" ? Это ее нажатие, перемещение, выполнение, скрытие?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно в обработчике нажатия отключить кнопку

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button.addActionListner(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
button.setEnabled(false);
}
});
```